# c program for calculating expressions

Tags: c

I have made this program to calculate expressions like '2 + 6 - 9'(with spaces between numbers and operators), but the last if block is not correct. How can I break the loop when \n is received, and also store the input if not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    char oper;
    int sum,y;
    scanf("%d %c",&sum,&oper);
    while(1)
    {
                scanf("%d",&y);

                if(oper=='+')
                        sum += y;
                else if(oper=='-')
                        sum -= y;
                else if(oper=='/')
                        sum /= y;
                else if(oper=='*')
                        sum += y;
                if((scanf("%c",&oper))=='\n')
                        break;
        }
        printf("\n =%d",sum);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See [the documentation for *scanf*](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

> On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled.

Replace this part:

```
if((scanf("%c",&oper))=='\n')
    break;
```

with:

```
if(scanf("%c",&oper) && oper=='\n')
    break;
```

This:

- checks whether `scanf()` has put any value into `oper`
- if yes then it checks if the value is equal to `\n`

Comment: with `if(scanf("%c",&oper) == 1 && oper=='\n')`.  Consider if  `scanf()` returned `EOF`.